# Not able to get correct number of Open File descriptor from node-exporter metrics

Tags: prometheus, grafana, prometheus-node-exporter

We are using node_exporter version 0.18.0

In Grafana Node Exporter dashboards, it shows the no of open file descriptors used by the Node Exporter process only, not the FDS used by the OS in that instance.

We are running node-exporter from root user.

**System Stats:**

Output of `lsof | wc -l` is `446732`

open files                      (-n) 400000

**Node Exporter Metrics:**

node_filefd_allocated 3232

node_filefd_maximum 1.508219e+06

node_scrape_collector_duration_seconds{collector="filefd"} 4.4016e-05

process_max_fds 1024

process_open_fds 9

Comment: I'm facing the same issue, surprisingly process_max_fds and process_open_fds is same across every box. If you found any workaround then please share.

Answer (score 6):

`node_filefd_allocated` is the metric you want.

Not everything that is listed by `lsof` uses a file descriptor on Linux, such as dynamically linked libraries.

> We are running node-exporter from root user.

The node exporter does not require root.